# Seeing possible floaters but only for 1-2 seconds

Tags: vision

I'm very stressed at this moment in time due to my mother having vascular dementia. I'm getting these floater-type things since about a month ago on the odd occasion. I'm not sure if they are floaters, though, since they fade away after only 1 or 2 seconds. Both eyes. And they seem to only occur when I'm feeling very stressed.

I do suffer from a huge number of floaters all across my vision, and especially when half closing my eyes. I'm just thinking that momentary bouts of stress might reduce the blood flow to my brain (or something), and be very briefly making some floaters more visible?